# Get Active window title in netbeans

Tags: netbeans

I wrote a JavaApplication with name JavaApplication5 in netbeans that gets active window title. This code runs in intellij but in netbeans gives error (`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`). How can I execute this program in netbeans without any error?

```
package javaapplication5;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.PointerByReference;

public class JavaApplication5
{
  private static final int MAX_TITLE_LENGTH = 1024;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String lastTitle = "none";
    String lastProcess = "none";
    long lastChange = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while (true)
    {
        String currentTitle = getActiveWindowTitle();
        String currentProcess = getActiveWindowProcess();
        if (!lastTitle.equals(currentTitle))
        {
            long change = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long time = (change - lastChange) / 1000;
            lastChange = change;
            System.out.println("Change! Last title: " + lastTitle + " lastProcess: " + lastProcess + " time: " + time + " seconds");
            lastTitle = currentTitle;
            lastProcess = currentProcess;
        }
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex)
        {
            // ignore
        }
    }
}

private static String getActiveWindowTitle()
{
    char[] buffer = new char[MAX_TITLE_LENGTH * 2];
    HWND foregroundWindow = User32DLL.GetForegroundWindow();
    User32DLL.GetWindowTextW(foregroundWindow, buffer, MAX_TITLE_LENGTH);
    String title = Native.toString(buffer);
    return title;
}

private static String getActiveWindowProcess()
{
    char[] buffer = new char[MAX_TITLE_LENGTH * 2];
    PointerByReference pointer = new PointerByReference();
    HWND foregroundWindow = User32DLL.GetForegroundWindow();
    User32DLL.GetWindowThreadProcessId(foregroundWindow, pointer);
    Pointer process = Kernel32.OpenProcess(Kernel32.PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | Kernel32.PROCESS_VM_READ, false, pointer.getValue());
    Psapi.GetModuleBaseNameW(process, null, buffer, MAX_TITLE_LENGTH);
    String processName = Native.toString(buffer);
    return processName;
}

static class Psapi
{
    static
    {
        Native.register("psapi");
    }

    public static native int GetModuleBaseNameW(Pointer hProcess, Pointer hmodule, char[] lpBaseName, int size);
}

static class Kernel32
{
    static
    {
        Native.register("kernel32");
    }

    public static int PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400;
    public static int PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010;

    public static native Pointer OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, boolean bInheritHandle, Pointer pointer);
}

static class User32DLL
{
    static
    {
        Native.register("user32");
    }

    public static native int GetWindowThreadProcessId(HWND hWnd, PointerByReference pref);
    public static native HWND GetForegroundWindow();
    public static native int GetWindowTextW(HWND hWnd, char[] lpString, int nMaxCount);
}
}
```

Comment: We're going to need some code and/or the complete exception to be able to help you.